# Three waves refraction?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, mathematics

This is more of a mathematical question, so I apologize in advance, but I thought, that maybe there is a situation from physics where "three waves interact":

(originally asked [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/411945/three-questions-about-three-functions-similar-to-sin-cos))

[Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410600/the-basel-problem-revisited) a question about the function, similar to sinc, $f(x)$ was asked:

$$f(x) = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left ( 1- \frac{x^3}{n^3} \right ) = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left ( 1- \frac{x}{n} \right ) \left ( 1- \frac{x}{n}\omega \right )\left ( 1- \frac{x}{n} \omega^2 \right )$$

which was shown to be equal to:

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{3k}\zeta_k(3)(-1)^k$$

where we have defined:

$$\zeta_k(3) = \sum_{1\le n_1 <n_2 \cdots <n_k} \left(\frac{1}{n_1 n_2 \cdots n_k} \right) ^3$$

and which is also equal to:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(1+x)\Gamma(1+\omega x) \Gamma(1+\omega^2 x)}$$

Let me define similar to $\sin,\cos$ functions $c_0,c_1,c_2$ where $c_0$ corresponds to $\sin$:

Let $c_0(x) = x f(\frac{x}{\pi})$. Then $c_0( \omega x ) = \omega x f(\frac{\omega x}{\pi}) = \omega x f(\frac{x}{\pi}) = \omega c_0(x)$ and similariliy $c_0(\omega^2x) = \omega^2 c_0(x)$.

From this it follows that $$c_0(x) + c_0(\omega x) + c_0(\omega^2 x ) = (1+\omega + \omega^2) c_0(x) = 0$$

We have:
$$c_0'(x) = f\left(\frac{x}{\pi}\right) + x f'\left(\frac{x}{\pi}\right)\frac{1}{\pi} =  f\left(\frac{x}{\pi}\right) +  f'\left(\frac{x}{\pi}\right)\frac{x}{\pi}$$
which is equal to
$$ = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{3k}}{\pi^{3k}} \zeta_k(3)(-1)^k + \frac{x}{\pi}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{3k x^{3k-1}}{\pi^{3k-1}} \zeta_k(3)(-1)^k$$
and this is equal to
$$ = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(3k+1)x^{3k}}{\pi^{3k}} \zeta_k(3)(-1)^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(3k+1)\zeta_k(3)(-1)^k}{\pi^{3k}}  x^{3k}$$

Let

$$c_1(x) := c_0\left(\frac{\pi}{3}+\omega x\right), c_2(x) := c_1\left(\frac{\pi}{3}+\omega x\right) = c_0 \left( \frac{\pi}{3}+\omega \frac{\pi}{3} + \omega^2 x\right)$$

then we also have:

$$c_2\left(\frac{\pi}{3}+\omega x\right) = c_0(x)$$

(mathematical) Question: (You can ignore this if you want).

1. Do the $c_0,c_1,c_2$ satisfy an "addition formula" similar to $\sin,\cos$?
2. Is there a relationship, similar to $\sin,\cos$, between the derivatives of these functions?
3. Is there a geometric interpretation of these functions?

**Physics question**:
**Is there any situation in physics where the threefold symmetry of the picture below represents three waves refracting / interacting?**

I have plotted $c_0(x)$ ($c_1(x)$ and $c_2(x)$ look similar) and it shows a three-fold symmetry, like there are three waves which meet at a threefold star and do a physical refraction:

[image: threefold_symmetry_waves]

Comment: Imo it might be better to remove the "mathematical question" from this post and only focus on the physics here.